# Dynamically change for-loop range in Java

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to increase the for-loop range in java? I have the following code:

```
for (DataRoot bri : Ri)
    {
        for (DataRoot brcom : complemento)
        {
            if (bri.getMesa().equals(brcom.getMesa()))
            {
                if (found) {found = false; break;}
                postrecom = brcom.getOrden().getPostres();
                Calendar dateri = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar datecom = Calendar.getInstance();
                dateri.setTime(bri.getFechaorden());

                for (Postres proc : postrecom)
                {
                   // if (found) {found = false; break;}
                    datecom.setTime(proc.getHora_plato());
                    long diff = datecom.getTimeInMillis() - dateri.getTimeInMillis();

                    if ( diff > (3*60*1000))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        Ri.add(brcom);
                        break;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bri.getOrden().getPostres().add(proc);
                        setBase();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

As you can notice, if some conditions are met, the Array "Ri" which is the main array will increase its content, lets say from 3 items to 4, at the start, the loop was going to be from 0 to 2 but as it got a new element I need it to keep running from 0 to 3 but the range will not dynamically increase as new items are added.

I could count how many items I added to "Ri" So that I can call that many times this method but if I do so, the compiler witll give me the "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" error at this point I dont know what to do any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wow three nested loops.  I do not understand why you are looping through  `RI` as `complemento` is not a child of `RI`

Comment: complemento is the complement of Ri, is data that is missing from RI and IF some conditions are met, it can be added to Ri i need to compare the "mesa" field in boths Ri and complemento, IF mesa is the same then i check another sub array, they are arrays within arrays within arrays, thats why you see 3 nested loops

Comment: I would just loop once then are then try to `get` the record from the other `List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well im relatively new developing in Java and seems like if you do loop type For-each like

```
for (Arraylist arraylist : size)
   {
      ....
   }
```

assuming your initial size was 2, meaning that the array contains 2 elements, IF in the process you add elements to the array, the size wont dynamically change BUT if you go for the old

```
for (int i = 0; i < Arraylist.size(); i++)
    {
      ....
    }
```

and in the process you add elements to the Array, the size of the loop gets re-calculated dynamically as you add new elements to the array and in my case, solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but from the explanation you have given and code you have written, you are trying to get `complement` Items and then add them to `Ri` list if not present.

Assuming data structure of Ri is ArrayList, the way I would approach is that, first I would get all the `complement` items. Then loop through complement items, and for each complement item, loop through the entire Ri value and set a boolean if the associated value is suitable to add like below :

```
for(dataBri brCom : complemento) {
   boolean shouldAdd = false;
    for (DataBri bri : Ri) {
     if(someConditionMet) {
       shouldAdd = true;
    }
     if (shouldAdd) {
       Ri.add(brCom);
     }
}
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: if i do that which i just did, following your idea, it gives me the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException... whats the thing with it? why i can not concurrently change an array if thats what i want? it is disgusting, any other ideas?

Comment: @MiguelSedek the you cannot run a for loop and change the element at the same time. It throws concurrentModException to protect itself from either going into infinite looping condition or trying to look for index in your list which no longer exists if you delete a given item.

Comment: Also, remember that the  for condition `for (DataRoot bri : Ri)` goes inside now. I just gave you a rough snipper to give the idea

Comment: yeah i know, but anyways I managed to keep the same structure, just changed for each to just for to and that did the trick since the for to range does change dynamically as you add or remove items